# How to invoke a local function during pulumi preview

Tags: node.js, pulumi

We've got a Node.js app that our devops manages with pulumi. The app has a local module with a default async function that runs some checks on the database. I'm trying to find documentation on how to best invoke that function during pulumi preview and/or pulumi up and if the best approach is to simply call it in index.ts

https://github.com/pulumi/automation-api-examples/blob/main/nodejs/remoteDeployment-tsnode/index.ts

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I know the entire questions context here, but let's start a thread. I use TS for our pulumi code as well.

For an example we have a job that needs to invoke a DMS job in AWS that updates the states in a Postgres database. For this you can create a separate TS file and make a function in there called update. That update function then imports the boto3 library so that it can make the appropriate connections to AWS. Then you can import that update function and call it from the main TS file.

Is that the kind of thing you are talking about?

Comment: Hey AndrewG, what I'm trying to do is call that 'update' function during the deploy process.